# Angular 'ngModelOptions' usage with 'input' results in template parse error

Tags: angular

The purpose of using ngModelOptions with input was to disallow invalid values added to model object as part of 2 way binding.Below is code snippet:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="xx" [formControl]="dob" 
placeholder="00/00/0000" [ngModelOptions]="{allowInvalid: false}" 
[(ngModel)]="xx.dob" minlength="10" maxlength="10" />
```

- error on browser console:
  compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
  Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
- question: 
  In order to disallow invalid values binding to ngModel is this the correct approach used above ? Is usage of ngModelOptions allowed in angular? Also I know (ngModelChange) could be used to  set only valid values to model object. But I was trying to achieve this with two way binding [(ngModel)] and [ngModelOptions]. Also I could use formControl's valuechanges to achieve the said behaviour but due to some reason we are using [(ngModel)] approach. We are using Angular4.x 
  Also I am new to Angular so please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I assume you get the error because `FormsModule` is not listed in

```
@NgModule({..., imports: [FormsModule], ...}) 
export class MyModule {}
```

2. `ngModelOptions` currently supports only the parameters `name`, `standalone`, and since Angular 5 `onUpdate`

See also https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options

As far as I know you can't prevent invalid values, at least not declaratively. You can act on validation errors.

See also https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges (should be exposed by the form)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! As per 1. in your answer I verified and FormsModule is present in @NgModule in my AppModule.

Comment: Is `AppModule` the only module in your applications code?

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: yes, AppModule is only module and angular version is 4.3.2 in our app

Comment: It might be the combination of `[formControl]="..."` with `[(ngModel)]="..."` `formControl` is for model-driven forms, `ngModel` for template-driven forms.

Comment: There's a little typo. The third parameter is 'updateOn' instead of onUpdate.